# How to increase data training bias in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am currently using about 15k images (50% good and bad) for a binary model training using Keras. However, my bad data set is limited. So I added augmentation. Still, I would like to force the model to recognize even good as bad if it is slightly or close to bad.

```
Y_train = train_generator.classes
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
class_weight = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced'
                                               ,np.unique(Y_train)
                                               ,Y_train)
class_weight
class_weight = dict(zip(np.unique(Y_train), class_weight))
class_weight
```

Output :

```
{0: 1.0015690376569037, 1: 0.9984358706986444}
```

I would like to force more training on the bad data set than a good data set. Is it possible to increase class (0 - bad) weight to like 10?

Training :

```
print(colored('Training initiaited. please wait........', 'blue',))
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                         epochs = epochs,
                         validation_data = validation_generator,
                         class_weight = class_weight, 
                         steps_per_epoch=int(train_generator.samples/batch_size),
                         callbacks=callbacks_list, 
                         validation_steps = int(validation_generator.samples/batch_size)
                           )
```

What's the best way to force the model to train more on bad data set? (if this is not the best way (unfortunately I don't have any bad data but I do have many good data points))

Is there anything I could do with following "balanced"?

```
class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced'
                                               ,np.unique(Y_train)
                                               ,Y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to have a tighter constraint on the false positives is to increase the threshold during classification. ie, say your model throws an output of `0.65`, while making the decision for the image class which is usually something like

```
threshold = 0.5
if output<threshold:
    print("Class 0")
else:
    print("Class 1")
```

it outputs as `class 0` but by increasing the threshold to say `0.80` you get a tighter bound on the true positives. The above is only good if your model throws outputs with corresponds to probability of class.

`But the correct way would be to choose the correct metric, for example in your case going with precision is a better option.`